# How do I find the public key of a bitcoin address?

Tags: public-key

I want to know the public key of my bitcoin address, (e.g. `13mtYzgprJuLUWw1EVWSPPuC88q7fGuSX1`), how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Get the private key of your address, then go to brainwallet.org, and switch the tab to Generator->Private Key, then paste in your private key. Your address should show up on the right. If it doesn't try switching it to Compressed. Your public key (in hex) will be the thing marked Public Key (SEC).